# What does this command do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I found this command:

```
execute at [@a] [nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{kill:3}}}] run kill [@e] [distance=..3, nbt=!{SelectedItem:{tag:{kill:3}}}]
```

But I don't know what it will do. What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

For everyone... (players only)

```
execute at [@a]
```

... who are holding (`SelectedItem`) an item with `{tag:{kill:3}}`

```
[nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{kill:3}}}]
```

do...

```
run
```

`/kill`

```
kill
```

all entities

```
[@e]
```

that are within 3 blocks

```
[distance=..3
```

and not have an item in their hand with `{tag:{kill:3}}` in its data.

```
, nbt=!{SelectedItem:{tag:{kill:3}}}]
```